# How to force to use older library

Tags: server, apt, ssh

I am newbie with Ubuntu and I am using Ubuntu server 12 LTS. On this server I would like to install openssh server in 5.3p1 version (the version is very import for my test; link to package:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/i386/openssh-server/1:5.3p1-3ubuntu3)

Unfortunately openSSH require library libssl in version 0.9.8 while Ubuntu 12 default version is 1.0.0. So my first step was to install libssl0.9.8. Unfortunately during installation I receive an error that says that version 1.0.0 is not supported. I wonder if it is possible to force installer to find and use libssl0.9.8?

My first attempt to solve the problem was to remove libssl1.0.0 and then install libssl0.9.8, but removal libssl1.0.0 affect so many other packets that many of my services stop working properly.

Has anyone come across this or does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe you can head over to http://ftp.fr.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/ and build from source the version you'd like to use?

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands to build from source the version you want.

```
wget -P ~/Desktop "ftp.fr.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/openssh-5.3.tar.gz"
cd ~/Desktop
gtar -xzvf openssh-5.3.tar.gz
cd /ssh/ssh
make
```

Comment: Unfortunately this version of ssh is designed for BSD system and Makefile is written in BSD make format not in GNU make.  Because of that command make display an error like that:
'Makefile:448: *** missing separator. Stop. error'